# How to link main.c to another C file from different directory in Xcode Project

Tags: c

In the Xcode project with languages as C.

- heap

  - heap_sort.c
  - heap_sort.c
- main.c

**this is the heap_sort.c file**

```
#include "heap_sort.h"

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;

}
```

**this is the heap_sort.h file**

```
#ifndef heap_sort_h
#define heap_sort_h

#include <stdio.h>

#endif /* heap_sort_h */
```

[this is the screenshot for my code in Xcode. I just wanted to import a function name **sum** to my main.c file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc5ld.png)

**this is the main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "heap/heap_sort.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int s;
    s = sum(3,5);
    printf("The integer is: %d\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance.Please try to have a look at screenshot first.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text (or links to pictures of text). Just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Hi larsks, thanks for reaching out..!! doing that.

Comment: @larsks I've tried my best to explain. Please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Your main file doesn't have a declaration for `sum`, so it doesn't know how to call it properly.

This declaration should go in your header file:

```
#ifndef heap_sort_h
#define heap_sort_h

int sum(int a, int b);

#endif /* heap_sort_h */
```

Comment: but if I am importing the function keeping the heap_sort.c outside of the heap directory parallel to main.c  then it's working.